# Moving labels above the rect in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm very new to d3.js and I tried creating a very simple progress [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4hyj8mu2/162/).

The code is:

```
var data = [2000, 200]; // here are the data values; v1 = total, v2 = current value

  var chart = d3.select("#container").append("svg") // creating the svg object inside the 
    .attr("class", "chart")
    .attr("width", 400) // bar has a fixed width
    .attr("height", 30 * data.length);

  var x = d3.scale.linear() // takes the fixed width and creates the percentage from the data
    .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
    .range([0, 400]); 

  chart.selectAll("rect") // this is what actually creates the bars
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("width", x)
    .attr("height", 10)
    .attr("rx", 5) // rounded corners
    .attr("ry", 5);

 var text = [0,200,2000]   

  chart.selectAll("text") // adding the text labels to the bar
    .data(text)
    .enter().append("text")
    .attr("x", x)
    .attr("y", 20) // y position of the text inside bar
    .attr("dx", -3) // padding-right
    .attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align: middle
    .attr("text-anchor", "end") // text-align: right
    .text(String);
```

Its rendering the graph. Have some couple of issues here:

1. For the text, I'm rendering `0` always, but its not visible.
2. I want the current value text to be displayed below and start and end should be moved above the markers.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For displaying any text above the rect you have to move it down a bit.

Regarding the texts, you can set different anchors...

```
.attr("text-anchor", function(_, i) {
   return ["start", "middle", "end"][i]
})
```

... and different vertical positions using the index:

```
.attr("y", function(_, i) {
    return i === 1 ? 36 : 10;
})
```

Here is the updated code:

```js
var data = [2000, 200]; // here are the data values; v1 = total, v2 = current value

var chart = d3.select("#container").append("svg") // creating the svg object inside the 
  .attr("class", "chart")
  .attr("width", 400) // bar has a fixed width
  .attr("height", 30 * data.length);

var x = d3.scale.linear() // takes the fixed width and creates the percentage from the data
  .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
  .range([0, 400]);

chart.selectAll("rect") // this is what actually creates the bars
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("y", 18)
  .attr("width", x)
  .attr("height", 10)
  .attr("rx", 5) // rounded corners
  .attr("ry", 5);

var text = [0, 200, 2000]

chart.selectAll("text") // adding the text labels to the bar
  .data(text)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .attr("x", x)
  .attr("y", function(_, i) {
    return i === 1 ? 36 : 10;
  }) // y position of the text inside bar // padding-right
  .attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align: middle
  .attr("text-anchor", function(_, i) {
    return ["start", "middle", "end"][i]
  }) // text-align: right
  .text(String);
```

```css
.chart rect:first-of-type {
  color: #fff;
  stroke: #3994b6;
  fill: white;
}

#container {
  padding: 30px
}

text:first-of-type {
  fill: #3994b6;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.chart rect:nth-of-type(2) {
  color: #fff;
  stroke: transparent;
  fill: #3994b6;
}

text:nth-of-type(2) {
  fill: #a8d4e4;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.chart rect:nth-of-type(3) {
  color: #fff;
  stroke: transparent;
  fill: #3994b6;
}

text:nth-of-type(3) {
  fill: #a8d4e4;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Awesome! One quick question, if the `data` is `data = [1000, 0];`, then the label `0` is getting chopped. Any guess why thats happening?

Comment: Well, I just tried those values and it was not chopped. Please show me in a jsfiddle.

Comment: That's because you don't have any left/right margin in that SVG: https://jsfiddle.net/Lb55ukar/ I hardcoded them, but the best idea is specifying them and changing the scale's range accordingly.

Comment: Great this should keep me started!